# Naming the mathematical subject of dynamical systems of non-linear differential equations

Tags: terminology, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to learn myself more about non-linear differential equations and how I can use them in modeling of complex systems. However, I'm struggling in finding the correct "subject" name of this field of mathematics.

I am wondering if there is a common name for a subject regarding solving systems of non-linear differential equations. I have already been through linear algebra, however, If I understand correctly. This can't be applied to non-linear equations.

An example of what I want to model:

The control system of a spacecraft traveling through multiple atmospheric conditions which are all modeled with non-linear equations, which each of these depend on different parts of information about the spacecrafts speed, mass, surface etc.

So simply, what branch of mathematics is this? and what kind of mathematics category books should I look for?

Comment: I'm not well studied but Diophantine analysis or something seems something close to me.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Me neither. I'm just trying to figure out what's next in the mathematical category of creating more complex models of systems of equations. Especially non-linear ones, since I've already been through the basics of the Linear Algebra course at University. So because of that I am trying to find the common name for this, so that I can find myself a decent book on that part of mathematics :)

Comment: *Dynamical systems* is mostly concerned with non-linear differential equations, hence this seems to be the name you are after. (And the subject certainly has nothing to do with "diophantine analysis"...)

Comment: And *control theory*. And *mathematical modelling*.

Comment: @Did Not entirely accurate: Diophantine approximations of irrational frequencies come up repeatedly in Hamiltonian dynamics and KAM theory.

Comment: @ABlumenthal Right, DA is a useful tool in this context then, certainly not the name of the subject (which might be a more proper formulation of the objection than in my first, too sweeping, comment).

Comment: Linear and nonlinear differential equations both are ordinary differential equations (ODE). Linear time invariant differential equations all have analytical solutions, however in general nonlinear differential equations do not. So often numerical methods are used to find a solution. These are called ODE solvers, such as Runge-Kutta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several fields dealing with this subject:

- Finding the differential equations that describe a problem would be the subject of **mathematical modelling** but also of a more applied discipline, such as **physics** or **engineering** in your example.
- Most interesting non-linear differential equations cannot be solved analytically.
  **Numerical analysis** addresses the question of how to find numerical solutions to these equations with given initial conditions.
- Understanding how the solutions to differential equations behave in general, how they change upon parameter changes, and so on would be the subject of the theory of **dynamical systems**.
  While this technically includes linear dynamical systems, they are well understood and boring from this field’s point of view.
- Finally, how to make a dynamical system that you can steer behave in a certain way (such as your rocket) sounds like **control theory** to be, but I am no expert on this.

Comment: To add on to this answer, I would also mention that "nonlinear equations" is a name sometimes used in the physics community to describe their own applied, numerical-based approach to dynamical systems theory.

Comment: @ABlumenthal: I have never heard it in that context and I am a physicist dealing with dynamical systems.